# Using case classes in lifted Slick

Tags: scala, slick

In ScalaQuery it seemed to be possible to use case classes in table definitions. e.g. https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/blob/master/src/test/scala/scala/slick/test/ql/MapperTest.scala#L26

But this syntax doesn't work in Slick. Specifically, the method `<>` is not available.

Is there a way to use case classes in lifted Slick without boilerplate mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It still works. See https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/1.0.1/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/MapperTest.scala . Be aware that you currently cannot map a single column, see https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/40 .

The error message you got could come from the component types of your projection not matching the component types of your case class. The <> method is added using an implicit conversion that is only applied if the types match.

Comment: The types didn't match because I had `Date`s in the case class and `Timestamps` in the projection.